# Select from multiple tables with UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

I've trying to select records from 3 tables in one database with `UNION` but I've got error:

> `#1248` - Every derived table must have its own alias

This is the query that I'm trying:

```
SELECT * from
  (SELECT column1, 'table1' from table1
UNION
   SELECT column1, 'table2'  from table2
UNION
   SELECT column1, 'table3'  from table3) 
WHERE column1 not like 'abr%' and length(column1) < 8;
```

What exactly mean that error and how can I fix it and show proper results?

Comment: Add alias for `'table1'` like `'table1' as t` and for your derived table  ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the derived table an alias like it says:

```
SELECT * from
  (SELECT column1, 'table1' from table1
UNION
   SELECT column1, 'table2'  from table2
UNION
   SELECT column1, 'table3'  from table3) dtAlias
WHERE column1 not like 'abr%' and length(column1) < 8;
```

Comment: The second condition `and length(column1) < 8` didn't work. It didn't show me results `< 8` symbols length. `not like 'abr%'` is working. What can be the problem?

Comment: try using `char_length(column1)`

Comment: Still second condition doesn't return anything even If I know that I have value wich is under 8 symbols.

Comment: Must be `OR length...` instead of `AND...` with or is working.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Alis.column1 
  FROM (SELECT column1, 'table1' as which from table1
  UNION ALL
      SELECT column1, 'table2' from table2
  UNION ALL
      SELECT column1, 'table3' from table3
 ) Alis
WHERE column1 not like 'abr%' and length(column1) < 8;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add an alias for your columns in an inner select or derived table and also for itself, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT column1, 'table1' as t from table1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT column1, 'table2' as t from table2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT column1, 'table3' as t from table3
    ) As dt
WHERE 
    column1 NOT LIKE 'abr%' 
  AND 
    length(column1) < 8;
```

**Edited :**
I change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` as a performance issue and there will not be any duplicates ;).

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, the problem is simple -- you need a table alias after the last parentheses.  You also need a column alias for the second column.

More important for performance reasons, is that you should use `UNION ALL`.  `UNION` incurs the overhead of removing duplicates, and that is totally unnecessary in this case:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT column1, 'table1' as which from table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT column1, 'table2' from table2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT column1, 'table3' from table3
     ) t
WHERE column1 not like 'abr%' and length(column1) < 8;
```

For performance in MySQL, I think you want to move the `WHERE` clause to the subqueries *and* create an index on `column1` in all three tables:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT column1, 'table1' as which from table1 WHERE column1 not like 'abr%' and length(column1) < 8
      UNION ALL
      SELECT column1, 'table2' from table2 WHERE column1 not like 'abr%' and length(column1) < 8
      UNION ALL
      SELECT column1, 'table3' from table3 WHERE column1 not like 'abr%' and length(column1) < 8
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank's for this but second condition `and length(column1) < 8` doesn't seems to work.

Comment: What do you mean id doesn't work?  It seems to work in all the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

you should give a name for the derived table as below

```
SELECT * from
  (SELECT column1, 'table1' from table1
UNION
   SELECT column1, 'table2'  from table2
UNION
   SELECT column1, 'table3'  from table3) as new_table
WHERE column1 not like 'abr%' and length(column1) < 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explainatory, you just need to name the derived table you created with the nested selections and unions.
It should be sufficient adding the alias to fix our error, something like this:

```
  SELECT * from
  (SELECT column1, 'table1' from table1
   UNION
   SELECT column1, 'table2'  from table2
   UNION
   SELECT column1, 'table3'  from table3) as youralias 
   WHERE column1 not like 'abr%' and length(column1) < 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add aliases to the tables which you use in subqueries. Here's the correct version:

```
USE test2;

SELECT * from
  (SELECT column1, 'table1' from table1 as t1
UNION
   SELECT column1, 'table2'  from table2 as t2
UNION
   SELECT column1, 'table3'  from table3) as t3
WHERE column1 not like 'abr%' and length(column1) < 8;
```